# trying to get jscrollpane working for the first time, without success!

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I am trying to get jscrollpane working on a very simple page, but for some reason it is not working.  An image which has normal scrollbars when I remove the script for jscrollpane, but which has no scrollbars when I include it.  I wonder if someone could have a look and see if there is anything obviously wrong.

Thanks

Nick

```
http://nickharambee.dyndns.org/examples/jscrollpane.html

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<head>

<!-- styles needed by jScrollPane -->
<link type="text/css" href="jquery.jscrollpane.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- the mousewheel plugin - optional to provide mousewheel support -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>

<!-- the jScrollPane script -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function()
    {
        $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
    });
</script>

<style>

.scroll-pane {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}
</style>
</head>


<html>
<body>

<div class="scroll-pane"><img src="../files/nancy.jpg"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your `jscrollpane` script tag loading? Be sure that the file you're pointing at is actually there.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
```

If you have a browser with a Javascript Console (e.g., Safari, Chrome, or Firefox w/ Firebug) then you can type `$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane` and if that is `undefined` then the library isn't loading properly.

Comment: thanks for your response.  for some reason it started working! i'm not sure why.  thanks also for the console tip.  handy.